# form: Textarea must be empty : it is warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting this warning like `form:textarea must be empty` when I am trying to add `<textarea>` in `jsp` file.

```
<TD align="right"><form:textarea  path="moduleDescription"  rows="5" cols="30"><spring:message text="Module Description :  "/></form:textarea></TD>
<TD align="left"><form:input path="moduleDescription" /></TD>
```

My question is how to set some default vale in the text area.

Comment: And so what? What do you expect? What are you asking here?

Comment: how to set default valeu in textarea

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a default value for your textarea you should use the `value` attribute

`<form:textarea path="moduleDescription" value="your default value, probably passed as a ${parameter} coming from the model ;-)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If still actual for somebody, refer to this question, it actually provided me with the solution to the identical problem:
[Initial value to textarea field in form tld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201229/initial-value-to-textarea-field-in-form-tld?rq=1)